# How can I get input value by increasing inputs id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic input adder, every time I add an input, the input id number increases .

I want the last input value, so I tried to use var for declaring the last key id.

```
key=$("#key"+ intId +"");
var val=$("#val"+ intId +"");
```

But that didn't work, because it alerts the value as undefined.

Also I wanted to alert the removed input value, but no success.

**Why can't I get the `key` and `val` values ?**

**Is there any other solution for selecting the last `key` `val` input values and the removed input value ?**

**HTML**

```
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
<input type="text" class="key" />
<input type="text" class="val" />
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="+" class="add" id="add" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#add").click(function() {
var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"setk\" id=\"key"+ intId +"\" />");
var fType = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"setv\" id=\"val"+ intId +" \" />");
var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"X\" />");
var key=$("#key"+ intId +"");
var val=$("#val"+ intId +"");
var set=$(".setk");
console.log(set.length);
console.log(key);
console.log(key.val());
console.log($("#key1").val());
removeButton.click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    alert("Removed "+key.val())
    //message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("del "+key.val()+"");
    //message.destinationName = "dev1/cfg";
    //mqtt.send(message);
});
fieldWrapper.append(fName);
fieldWrapper.append(fType);
fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
$("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
alert("Set "+key.val()+" "+val.val());
//message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("set "+key.val()+" "+val.val());
//message.destinationName = "dev1/cfg";
//mqtt.send(message);
```

});

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"setk\" id=\"key"+ intId +"\" />");
        var fType = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"setv\" id=\"val"+ intId +" \" />");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"X\" />");
        var key=$("#key"+ intId +"");
        var val=$("#val"+ intId +"");
        var set=$(".setk");
        console.log(set.length);
        console.log(key);
        console.log(key.val());
        console.log($("#key1").val());
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            alert("Removed "+key.val())
;
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
        alert("Set "+key.val()+" "+val.val());

      
    });
```

```css
fieldset
{
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    margin:5px 0px;
    height:100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

input.add
{
    float:left;
}
input.fieldname
{

}
select.fieldtype
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
input.remove
{
}
#yourform label
{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
#yourform input, #yourform textarea
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
<input type="text" class="key" />
<input type="text" class="val" />
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="+" class="add" id="add" />
```

Comment: i think this is helpful to you. `http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/`

Comment: You can't get the value of "key" and "Val" since they haven't been added to the content yet.

Comment: In your `alert("Set " + key.val() + " " + val.val());` val and key have been added but the value is empty so why do you expect it to have any value?

Comment: on the first execution there's no such element as `var key=$("#key"+ intId +"");` - you haven't added it to the DOM yet. If you called it after the line `fieldWrapper.append(fName);` it should work. OTOH you could just use the fName variable instead of trying to fetch it again.

Comment: why complicating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JS instead of yours:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"setk\" id=\"key" + intId + "\" />");
    var fType = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"setv\" id=\"val" + intId + " \" />");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"X\" />");
    //Add objects to html
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fType);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    //Then use
    var key = $("#key" + intId + "");
    var val = $("#val" + intId + "");
    var set = $(".setk");
    console.log(set.length);
    console.log(key);
    console.log(fName.val());
    console.log($("#key1").val());
    removeButton.click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        alert("Removed " + key.val())
    });
    alert("Set " + key.val() + " " + val.val());
});
```